# Add reference to class containing disallowed services

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

So, here is my issue in a nutshell: I have a class that I want to make available to two projects in my solution - The main project for my app and the AudioPlaybackAgent project. However, Visual Studio doesn't let me reference the class in AudioPlaybackAgent because the class utilizes BackgroundTransferService (which is not allowed in the AudioPlaybackAgent).

My workaround to this has been to create an instance of the class in each project with the disallowed method omitted from AudioPlaybackAgent. Is there another way of doing this? Is it possible to use conditionals in some way? It is becoming very unruly and tedious maunually syncing properties/fields/methods between the two class instances.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe it means you should have two classes instead of one? Put the BackgroundTransferService logic in another class, and reference the current class (stripped of its BackgroundTransferService logic) in a property. That or use inheritance to add additional logic to your class without having to manually sync the fields.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will give this a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Add BACKGROUNDTRANSEFER in the project settings, Build => Conditional compilation symbols.
Where it's allowed.

```
#if BACKGROUNDTRANSEFER
... disallowed code
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will give this a shot and report back.